# Wrong answer in UVa online judge

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a really simple problem on UVa online judge. The problem code is: 10071. You can find the problem here: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=94
My code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int v,t,a,d;
   cin >> v >> t;
   t = t*2; 
  d = (v)*t;
  cout << d << endl;
}
```

But it says wrong answer. What went wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not read the complete question.

Correct solution is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    while(scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)==2)
    {
        printf("%d\n",(a*b)*2);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you may notice above, there can be multiple test cases. You have to account for it. So I have a while loop for it.